# Sqlalchemy check constraint on count of column

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have this table in sqlalchemy:

```
class Table(Model):
  __table_name__ = 'tbl'
  col1 = Column(Integer)
  col2 = Column(Integer)
```

I want to add this constraint to my model:

```
check ( count ( select * 
                from tbl t1, tbl t2
                where t1.clo2=t2.col2) < 3)
```

I put this query in `CheckConstraint` but not works.

Comment: what is m1, m2? you mean t1,t2? Also, you don't need to use tbl as t1?

Comment: yeah. I edited that mistake